# Creating a function that receives the taxonomy terms that have been changed in a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, hooks, terms

Ive been looking into actions and hooks etc... from wordpress, but cant seem to do a very simple thing. I just want to execute a function whenever a post is updated, and within the function I want the names of the terms that have been changed on that save. So maybe some sort of before and after comparison of terms??

Could somebody please just give me a hint at the direction to go in? I started off with:

```
add_action('save_post', 'myFunction');
```

But I cant seem to pass the before and after taxonomy terms to it for a comparison to see which have just been selected.. if that makes sense.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After WordPress has updated a posts' taxonomy terms it triggers the action:

```
set_object_terms
```

([see source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2213)) which passes 6 variables:

1. Object ID
2. Terms that were assigned to the post (or added depending on 5) (could be their slug or term ID).
3. Taxonomy-term IDs of above (not term IDs)
4. The taxonomy
5. Append. If true - terms in 2 are added to existing terms. If false (default) terms replace the existing terms.
6. The post's terms before updating (as taxonomy-term IDs)

#### Problem 1

Unfortunately there is no way of knowing if that object refers to post, or something (like a user). That might be a way hooking onto `set_object_terms` only when you can be sure that when its next fired, it refers to a post.

#### Problem 2

The IDs are passed are taxonomy-term IDs, not term-IDs - and most WordPress functions use the term ID. So you'll probably need to get the term ID (and taxonomy) from the taxonomy term ID to do anything useful. A potential work around is, since we know the taxonomy, list all the terms and do a simple `foreach` loop and filter them. **Better suggestions are welcome**

*The following is untested.*

```
 add_action('set_object_terms','wpse61678_terms_changed',10,6);

 function wpse61678_terms_changed($object_id, $terms, $tt_ids, $taxonomy, $append, $old_tt_ids){

      //Note problem 1 - we might not necessarily know what $object_id refers to. 

     //Added terms are specified terms, that did not already exist
     $added_tt_ids = array_diff($tt_ids, $old_tt_ids);

     if( $append ){
         //If appending terms - nothing was removed
         $removed_tt_ids = array();
     }else{
         //Removed terms will be old terms, that were not specified in $tt_ids
         $removed_tt_ids = array_diff($old_tt_ids, $tt_ids);
     }

    /*Note problem 2, we would preferably like the term objects / IDs, 
      Currently we have the taxonomy term IDs*/

    //Get all terms
    $all_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array('hide_empty'=>0));

    $removed_terms =array()
    $added_terms =array();
    foreach( $all_terms as $term ){
         $tt_id = (int) $term->term_taxonomy_id;
         if( in_array( $tt_id, $removed_tt_ids) ){
             $removed_terms[] = $term;
         }elseif( in_array( $tt_id, $added_tt_ids) ){
             $added_terms[] = $term;
         }
    }

    //$added_terms contains added term objects
    //$removed_terms contains removed term objects


 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the lengthy reply! I did try using set_object_terms, but came into trouble when I kept getting "missing argument" php errors pointing to the line of the function with all the parameters in.. I thought I was doing it wrong but I did what u have done above. The $object_id worked fine, but nothing else???

Comment: Yup, needed to set the number of arguments explicitly to 6. Updated now :).

Comment: YES!!! That is it!! Thank you so much :) I cant believe I didnt read the docs carefully enough to realise you had to specify that. Thought I was going insane lol. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

If there are **potential** problems with using the `set_object_terms` hook as pointed out by Stephen, possibly hooking into `pre_post_update` and then followed by `wp_insert_post`would suffice,

```
add_action('pre_post_update','get_terms_before_update');
function get_terms_before_update(){
    $terms_before = get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy );
    //do something else if required...
    return $terms_before; 
}

add_action('wp_insert_post','get_terms_after_update');
    function get_terms_after_update(){
    //pass in $terms_before from get_terms_before_update() function
    //compare terms
}
```

Comment: +1. This probably a more reliable solution. You could make into a class and store the variables as a class variable. `wp_insert_post` could be replaced with `save_post`.

Answer (score 3):

This is an update of Stephen's answer based the new get_terms_by function and assuming we know what taxonomy we want.

```
add_action('set_object_terms','save_terms',10,6);

function save_terms($object_id, $terms, $tt_ids, $taxonomy, $append, $old_tt_ids) {

    //Assuming we only want terms from specific taxonomy
    //If not simply remove this conditional
    $our_taxonomy = 'categories';
    if($taxonomy == $our_taxonomy){
        //Added terms are specified terms, that did not already exist
        $added_tt_ids = array_diff($tt_ids, $old_tt_ids);

        if ($append) {
            //If appending terms - nothing was removed
            $removed_tt_ids = array();
        } else {
            //Removed terms will be old terms, that were not specified in $tt_ids
            $removed_tt_ids = array_diff($old_tt_ids, $tt_ids);
        }

        /* Note problem 2 by Stephen, we would preferably like the term objects / IDs, 
          Currently we have the taxonomy term IDs */

        foreach($added_tt_ids as $term){
            $added_terms[] = get_term_by( 'term_taxonomy_id',$term,$taxonomy);
        }

        foreach($removed_tt_ids as $term){
            $removed_terms[] = get_term_by( 'term_taxonomy_id',$term,$taxonomy);
        }

        //$added_terms contains added term objects
        //$removed_terms contains removed term objects
    }
}
```